# How much RAM does a smart contract consume?

Tags: smart-contract, ram

I have a smart contract compiled resulting in a 10,961 Bytes wasm file and a 2,372 Bytes abi file. However, when deploying the contract on chain it consumes about 110,000 Bytes which is almost 10x the wasm+abi file.

Why is the on chain RAM consumption so much higher than what the binary files consume on my hard drive?

How can I estimate/calculate the on chain RAM usage of a compiled smart contract before deploying it?

Answer (score 2):

Deploying contract is done by two actions, `eosio::setcode` for wasm, and `eosio::setabi` for abi. `setcode` costs 10x the size of wasm file, but `setabi` costs the exact size of abi file.

Comment: But why does setcode consume 10 times of the size of the wasm file? Doesn't a normal c/c++ library/executable only consume as much RAM as their filesize? Why is that different for wasm/eosio? Thanks for the info so far.